# How can I layout a widget based on the size of its child?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build a container with width = (its child width + 10). the child is also a container with Text widget that can have variant text content.

I tried to extract child to a Statefull widget but I failed to expose its size.

Here is my minimal code:

```dart
  final GlobalKey _childKey = GlobalKey();

  _getChildWidth() {
    final Size size = _childKey.currentContext.size;
    final width = size.width;
    return width;
  }

  Widget child = Container(
    key: _keyChild,
    child: Text("text here"),
  );

  Widget parent = Container(
    width: _getChildWidth + 10,
    child: child,
  );
```

Comment: Can you add an image/prototype of how your UI must be? maybe there are a better way to do what you want...

Comment: @siega https://dribbble.com/shots/2704939-Messages a chat bubbles is a good example. The parent container's width is based on its child's text length.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the [`Padding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) widget, although `Container` also has a `padding` property: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/padding.html

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a container, place a horizontal padding property of 5 (5 left + 5 right) and a Text child, like this:

```
  Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      child: Text('text here'),
  );
```